# I deleted "Materials" in Unity and now the scripts added to a sphere don't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was creating an Unity program, and I deleted the "Materials" folder, because I didn't see anything in it.
Then, the sphere that I had bugged, so I deleted it and created a new one. I just added the Movement script to the new sphere.
I tested the program and the sphere didn't move, but the old moved. (I had already deleted the old, but I had the same conditions in the new sphere and the new didn't work).

There's the Movement Script (sorry if it shows with bad spacing, just copy and paste it, please):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float force = 150;
    Rigidbody rb;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 vector = new Vector3(h, 0.5f, v);
        rb.AddForce(vector * force * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: what IDE are you using that formats your code like that? ^^

Comment: Does the code throw any errors? Is there a rigidbody on the sphere?

Comment: Did you attach rigidbody component to the new sphere?

Comment: 1st comment: MonoDevelop

Comment: 2nd comment: The code doesn't throw errors

Comment: 3rd comment: I think that no, i just copypasted that code from internet.

Comment: Attach rigidbody to your sphere and disable gravity

Comment: 4th comment: Thank you, now it works.

Comment: @Myztery333 For future posts, you can @ someone instead of saying nth comment.

Comment: @funie200 ok I didn't know i'm new here